# Core Maths for GIS development

Tags: math, gis

Greetings,

I have an interview coming up in early February with a company developing GIS and fleet management products and was told that I will be given a number of Maths questions in the interview. I have done a bit of math at university though I now naturally want to go over/read up on what could be most relevant.

As Maths is quite broad, I was hoping that there might be some SO community members in the field of GIS that could recommend areas to read up on. I haven't been told what to expect, so my plan so far is to have a look at linear algebra, geometry and discrete math (never taken a discrete math course). I don't have too much time so I'd appreciate some suggestions on areas of Maths what you'd consider most fundamental for GIS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Trigonometry (2D and spherical), Mapping Projections, coordinate systems.

Answer (score 5):

[coordinate systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system) is a useful pick in any case. Also, [GPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System) related stuff and trigonometry could also be relevant.

Mitch Wheat mentioned subjects are covered in any Computer Graphics course book. Which is not GIS but worth the time.

Answer (score 2):

Since it is fleet management company you are applying I'd also have a look at some basic GIS network problems.  Something like shortest path algorithms, travelling salesman problem, routing, etc.

Have a look at 'Network and Location Analysis' chapter of [Geospatial Analysis](http://www.spatialanalysisonline.com/output/) book for a good starter on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

I had to learn quickly spherical trigonometry and I found the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_trigonometry) a great starting point.